# Ordered list with O(1) random access and removal

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Does there exist a data structure with the following properties:

- Elements are stored in some order
- Accessing the element at a given index takes O(1) time (possibly amortized)
- Removing an element takes amortized O(1) time, and changes the indices appropriately (so if element 0 is removed, the next access to element 0 should return the old element 1)

For context, I reduced an algorithm question from a programming competition to:

Over `m` queries, return the `k`th smallest positive number that hasn't been returned yet. You can assume the returned number is less than some constant `n`.

If the data structure above exists, then you can do this in `O(m)` time, by creating a list of numbers 1 to `n`. Then, for each query, find the element at index `k` and remove it. During the contest itself, my solution ended up being `O(m^2)` on certain inputs.

I'm pretty sure you can do this in `O(m log m)` with binary search trees, but I'm wondering if the ideal `O(m)` is reachable. Stuff I've found online tends to be close, but not quite there - the tricky part is that the elements you remove can be from anywhere in the list.

Comment: Use Quick Select algorithm.

Comment: A hashtable backed with self-balancing binary trees could probably get you pretty close to that performance.

Comment: Are there any constraints in the insert (or construction) operation?

Comment: @OneMoreError, I don't see how using quick select helps you here, since you want each query to run in sublinear time.

For construction/insert, let's say aim for at most `O(log n)` insert, since an `O(n)` insert isn't much better than using an ArrayList with `O(n)` remove for this problem.

Comment: I would guess that this kind of data structure does not exist in the RAM model. It would be used a ton if it did. The proof of it might be a tough one.

Comment: Why would you have to remove elements from the ArrayList? If the list is sorted, just increase the index. If it isn't, just swap and then use whatever mechanism you've got to find the next minimum. I'm still not clear on what sort of time constraints you're placing on the construction of your data structure.

Comment: The offline problem is decoding a [Lehmer code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code). *Encoding* a Lehmer code is at least as hard as computing the number of inversions, for which there are o(n log n)-time algorithms known but (I believe) no O(n)-time algorithms. I would expect a similar situation for decoding. Consider asking cstheory.

Comment: Btw, substituting general elements for 1..n is not necessary, since a data structure that required 1..n could be used to index into the original array.

Comment: You can do this in O(m log N) (`N` being the maximum value of `k`) with an [indexable skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist). It's unclear to me from your problem description whether the list will contain more than `m` items.

Comment: doubly linked list (DLL) in a hashmap would do?

Answer (score 8):

1. **well the `O(1)` removal is possible with `linked list`**

   each element has pointer to next and previous element so removal just deletes element and sets the pointers of its neighbors like:

   ```
   element[ix-1].next=element[ix+1].prev
   ```
2. **accessing ordered elements at index in `O(1)` can be done with `indexed arrays`**

   so you have unordered array like `dat[]` and index array like `idx[]` the access of element `ix` is just:

   ```
   dat[idx[ix]]
   ```
3. **Now the problem is to have these properties at once**

   you can try to have linked list with index array but the removal needs to update index table which is `O(N)` in the worst case.

   if you have just index array then the removal is also `O(N)`

   if you have the index in some form of a tree structure then the removal can be close to `O(log(N))` but the access will be also about `O(log(N))`

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a structure that would do both of this in O(n) time, where n was the number of points which had been removed, and not the total size. So if the number you're removing is small compared to the size of the array, it's close to O(1).

Basically, all the data is stored in an array. There is also a priority queue for deleted elements. Initialise like so:

```
Data = [0, 1, 2, ..., m]
removed = new list
```

Then, to remove an element, you add it's original index (see below for how to get this) to the priority queue (which is sorted by size of element with smallest at the front), and leave the array as is. So removing the 3rd element:

```
Data = [0, 1, 2, 3,..., m]
removed = 2
```

Then what's now the 4th and was the 5th:

```
Data = [0, 1, 2, 3,..., m]
removed = 2 -> 4
```

Then what's now the 3rd and was the 4th:

```
Data = [0, 1, 2, 3,..., m]
removed = 2 -> 3 -> 4
```

Now to access an element, you start with it's index. You then iterate along the removed list, increasing the index by one each time, until you reach an element which is larger than the increased value of the index. This will give you the original index(ie. position in Data) of the element you're looking for, and is the index you needed for removal.

This operation of iterating along the queue effectively increases the index by the number of elements before it that were removed.

Sorry if I haven't explained very well, it was clear in my head but hard to write down.

Comments:

- Access is O(n), with n number of removed items
- Removal is approximately twice the time of access, but still O(n)
- A disadvantage is that memory use doesn't shrink with removal.
- Could potentially 're-initialise' when removed list is large to reset memory use and access and removal times. This operation takes O(N), with N total array size.

So it's not quite what OP was looking for but in the right situation could be close.